# How do you get a list picker like the kind shown in the alarm clock?

Tags: list, windows-phone-7, datepicker, timepicker

How do you create the big, scrolling list picker, like the kind that is created for datePicker and timePicker which is used on the WP7 default alarm clock?  The remaining list pickers don't have quite the same effect.  I would be using the list pickers only to choose integer values.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` are controls that are provided by the [Silverlight Toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). What they actually do is present the selection in one control in your page, then navigate to a separate page that allows you to actually select a new date/time. In these separate pages they use a collection of `LoopingSelector` controls (one per item) that enable the user to select the parts of the date/time.

If you want to display a similar picker but for numeric values, then you need to implement the same infrstructure but using a single `LoopingSelector` and you need to provide the correct data source (that implements the `ILoopingSelectorDataSource` interface) that specifies the values for your control.

There is a great series of 3 posts on the `LoopingSelector` on [WindowsPhoneGeek.com](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API)