# A control for choosing a number from a list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

What would you recommend?

I was experimenting with ComboBox but it didn't seem to work right. I couldn't even find it in Assets in Blend and after I added it by editing xaml it just listed items like a table does. It wasn't even close to ComboBox I know from html..

Than I tried with ListPicker which eventually worked, but... when there are numbers from 1 to 59 to choose from it doesn't really look good.

Any help appreciated. Examples double appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely recommend the [LoopingSelector](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API) from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888). It is similar to the control used in the alarm app for setting the time.

[image: Sample LoopingSelector]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post.  The answer has a link to the Looping Selector:

[How do you get a list picker like the kind shown in the alarm clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296382/how-do-you-get-a-list-picker-like-the-kind-shown-in-the-alarm-clock)

Answer (score -1):

try one of these controls
all are suitable for dealing with lists.

```
ListView lv = new ListView()
TreeView tv = new TreeView()
ListBox lb = new ListBox()


    for(int i=0;i<int.MAXVALUE;i++)
    {
    lv.Items.Add(i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<int.MAXVALUE;i++)
    {
    tv.Nodes.Add(i);
    }


    for(int i=0;i<int.MAXVALUE;i++)
    {
    lb.Items.Add(i);
    }


private void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

MessageBox.Show(lv.SelectedItems[0].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(tv.SelectedNode.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(lb.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: maybe but anyway thanks for showing this twice. I think I got your notion through ur down vote. commenting seems excrescent. xD